# animatewithduration exponentially get faster

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I am currently developing an iOS app. In the app I have blocks(UIView's) falling from the top of the screen using a uiview animatewithduration. I am looking to have them exponentially get faster as they fall. Is there a way to do this using animatewithduration or is there another way you would try achieve the same effect?

Comment: If none of the built-in timing functions suit your demands, create a CAKeyFrameAnimation with your custom timing.

Answer (score 0):

You can increment your duration with a variable in the completion block and recall the animation. This would be a simple but effective way to do what you're asking.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:someVariable animations:^{

// Animation

}
completion:^ (BOOL finished) 
{
    if (finished) {
        // Increment your someVariable here 
        // Then just call this holding method again
    }
}];
```

Comment: but i would just be adding 100s of animations one on top of the next

Comment: Perhaps a particle emitter? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAEmitterLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: If you are getting really complex I would just recommend Cocos2d since it's designed exactly for those type of things and allows a lot more (easier) functionality with optimized performance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use CAAnimations with custom timing functions to do this. A small example:

```
CAMediaTimingFunction *timing = [[CAMediaTimingFunction alloc] initWithControlPoints:1 :0.1 :1 :0.9];
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
anim.timingFunction = timing;
anim.duration = 0.4;
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:480];
[view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

Comment: great can u please explain what these are initWithControlPoints:1 :0.1 :1 :0.9]; thanks

Comment: this are the controlpoints of a cubic [beziercurve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve). You can play with the paarameters with this nice [online tool](http://cubic-bezier.com) to get the curve you want.

Comment: it is working however when the speed is anything less then about 20 sec it jumps and is not a smooth action